# ASP.Net Core anchor tag helper as RESTful links

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I'm using anchor tags helpers, which work fine for the most part.  I'd like to clean up a particular URL that is getting generated,  My tag looks like this (note that type is more specific than id in this case, not that it matters):

```
<a asp-controller="SomeController" asp-action="SomeAction" asp-route-id="@Model.ID" asp-route-type="@someType">
```

I would like to get a URL that looks like this:

```
http://localhost:1234/SomeController/SomeAction/42/1
```

But instead I get

```
http://localhost:1234/SomeController/SomeAction/42?type=1
```

Is there any way to get the 'additional' parameter(s) in a RESTful format, instead of a GET string?  I could always just modify the route or URL in a more conventional manner, but was curious if I could make this work.

Comment: That’s not RESTful. RESTful is about resources and using HTTP verbs for actions. You are just embedding another query argument inside the path. – For configuring your routes, [see the documentation about routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing).

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question in the hopes that it benefits someone else.  The issue was that I needed to create a custom route, like the below:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "newRoute",
                template: "{controller=SomeController}/{action=SomeAction}/{id}/{type}");
```

Interested in alternative approaches, if there is a better practice.